# new line in vim doesn't display?

Tags: vim, ghci

I invoke `ghci` in **gvim** by using `:!ghci %` to load my haskell file, However, the newline is displayed as `^J` as the image below shows:

[image]

If I invoke ghci in **vim** instead of **gvim**, then everything is OK, so How could I get newline in gvim ?

Answer (score 0):

For the graphical version of Vim, GVIM, a crude built-in terminal emulation is used for shell commands (cp. `:help gui-shell`). As the help page mentions, this has some limitations, and it is not meant to be used for interactive commands.

Switching to Vim in a terminal will run the shell command inside the terminal (with full capabilities); I guess that would be the best alternative if you cannot live with the discrepancies, and don't want to launch a separate terminal from gvim (i.e. `:! xterm -e ghci %`)